# Eclipse syntax coloring on Netbeans

Tags: eclipse, netbeans, syntax-highlighting

I'm now using NetBeans as my Java IDE after having used Eclipse for a while.  Is there a way to export Eclipse's syntax highlighting settings for use in NetBeans, or otherwise configure NetBeans syntax highlighting to behave like Eclipse?

Comment: _The problem is that I'm very addicted to the syntax coloring on Eclipse_. Me too. Now I have to use Netbeans for a very specific task, but I like very much the eclipse coloring. +1

Answer (score 5):

@nmartins: I guess eclipse color syntax coloring in netbeans would be a manual process...you can try other available color profiles by going to

> netbeans->tools->options->Fonts &
>   Colors tab and choose different Profile from drop down and click OK.
>   You may find something closer to eclipse.

However you can get eclipse keyboard shortcuts in netbeans by selecting "eclipse" from drop-down in netbeans->tools->options->Keymap

Comment: While there is a quite good keyboard-shortcut for "Eclipse"-Users, there sadly is not even a remotely similar color-profile included.

Comment: Not exactly the answer I hoped for, but I guess this is the way I'll go. So I give the bounty to ag112. BTW: If I make a good color-configuration I'll come back here and make it available.

Comment: @Boris: Yes please let us know about your color configuration.Thanks.

Comment: Added the link in a new answer.

Answer (score 4):

As promised in my comment on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526287/eclipse-syntax-coloring-on-netbeans/6543717#6543717) I created a simple eclipse-color-scheme for netbeans. This does not claim to be complete at all, partly because some settings are just impossible in netbeans (and vice-versa it seems) and partly because this is sufficient for me at the moment.

I did put the config on github so it is easy to fork and modify if you feel something is missing and want to share your improvement.

https://github.com/Boris-de/eclipsecolors_for_netbeans

You can build the .zip yourself with maven or download a ready-to-use .zip at github.

Answer (score 3):

My advice is : "When in Rome do as the Romans do".

While it maybe perfectly possible to tweak everything to look exactly as in Netbeans, you're still gonna have a hard time setting it up, keeping it running. Also you'll inevitably run against subtle and not so subtle conflicts where some "compromise" needs to be found.

In the end it slows down your learning process of the new environment and you'll spend a lot of time learning things in the UI you probably did not really want to know anyway.

I recommend to give the defaults a try for 1-2 weeks and then tweak a couple of things you really cannot get used too.

Comment: I don't exactly agree with the *When in Rome do as the romans do*...  I develop under IntelliJ IDEA using Emacs shortcuts (and customized ones at that) and a reverse-video (GIYF) color scheme. So to *When in Rome do as the romans do* I answer: *Think outside the box* ;)

Comment: @SpoonBender I worked with a collegue who used Eclipse with Emacs shortcuts. When he had a problem with his code, we looked at it together, and I always had to tell him what I would like to do ("now open the quickfix menu" or "copy that part and paste it there"), or use the menus, instead of doing it with "Eclipse shortcuts". Therefore, I support the advice of using the standard settings of a program, unless they really hinder you. (I used to disable the Ctrl+D shortcut, because I hit it accidentally when aiming for Ctrl+S or Ctrl+F.)

Comment: @SpoonBender On the other hand, a program should support customization. Most programs I know don't correctly handle a white-on-black high contrast scheme (another collegue of mine uses it), and I have often seen dialogs printed white on white.